# How to speed up numpy dot product with masks?

Tags: arrays, performance, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have 2 numpy arrays, `m1` and `m2` where `m1` is size (nx1) and `m2` is size (1xn) and I want to perform the multiplication `m1.dot(m2)` resulting in a matrix `m` of size (nxn)

I want to compute an approximate `m_approx`, by only using the highest k elements in `m1` and `m2` and making all other elements 0(all elements are positive).

I am trying to speed up the multiplication because the size `n` for me is large (~10k). I want to pick a small `k` say 100 and really speed up the multiplication. I have tried using numpy sparse matrix which does make the dot product lot faster but it is very slow to convert m1 and m2 into sparse vectors. How can I achieve this? I feel masks might be a way to achieve this but not sure how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be solved using [`np.argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) to get the indices of largest `k` elements and [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) for selecting and setting the dot product of selected elements from `m1` and `m2`. So, we would have basically two stages to implement this, as discussed next.

First off, get the indices corresponding to largest `k` elements in `m1` and `m2`, like so -

```
m1_idx = np.argpartition(-m1,k,axis=0)[:k].ravel()
m2_idx = np.argpartition(-m2,k)[:,:k].ravel()
```

Finally, setup output array. Use `np.ix_` to broadcast the `m1` and `m2` indices along the rows and columns respectively for selecting elements in the output array that are to be set. Next up, calculate the dot product between the highest `k` elements from `m1` and `m2`, which could be obtained from `m1` and `m2` using indexing with `m1_idx` and `m2_idx`, like so -

```
out = np.zeros((n,n))
out[np.ix_(m1_idx,m2_idx)] = np.dot(m1[m1_idx],m2[:,m2_idx])
```

Let's verify the implementation with a sample run by running it against another implementation that does explicit setting of lower `n-k` elements as `0`s in `m1`, `m2` and then performing dot product. Here's a sample run to perform the check -

1) Inputs :

```
In [170]: m1
Out[170]: 
array([[ 0.26980423],
       [ 0.30698416],
       [ 0.60391089],
       [ 0.73246763],
       [ 0.35276247]])

In [171]: m2
Out[171]: array([[ 0.30523552, 0.87411242, 0.01071218, 0.81835438, 0.21693231]])

In [172]: k = 2
```

2) Run proposed implementation :

```
In [173]: # Proposed solution code
     ...: m1_idx = np.argpartition(-m1,k,axis=0)[:k].ravel()
     ...: m2_idx = np.argpartition(-m2,k)[:,:k].ravel()
     ...: out = np.zeros((n,n))
     ...: out[np.ix_(m1_idx,m2_idx)] = np.dot(m1[m1_idx],m2[:,m2_idx])
     ...:
```

3) Use alternative implementation to get the output :

```
In [174]: # Explicit setting of lower n-k elements to zeros for m1 and m2
     ...: m1[np.argpartition(-m1,k,axis=0)[k:]] = 0
     ...: m2[:,np.argpartition(-m2,k)[:,k:].ravel()] = 0
     ...: 

In [175]: m1  # Verify m1 and m2 have lower n-k elements set to 0s
Out[175]: 
array([[ 0.        ],
       [ 0.        ],
       [ 0.60391089],
       [ 0.73246763],
       [ 0.        ]])

In [176]: m2
Out[176]: array([[ 0.       , 0.87411242, 0.        , 0.81835438, 0.        ]])

In [177]: m1.dot(m2)  # Use m1.dot(m2) to directly get output. This is expensive.
Out[177]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.52788601,  0.        ,  0.49421312,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.64025905,  0.        ,  0.59941809,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

4) Verify our proposed implementation :

```
In [178]: out   # Print output from proposed solution obtained earlier
Out[178]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.52788601,  0.        ,  0.49421312,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.64025905,  0.        ,  0.59941809,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... did not know about np.ix_!

Comment: @Adi Glad to help! :)